# When do the set of functions generating an initial topology characterize all continuous functions?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Given a set $X$ with the initial topology wrt a set of functions $A = \{f:X \to \mathbb{C}\}$, clearly $A \subseteq C(X)$, the set of all continuous (complex valued) functions on $X$. When is $A = C(X)$? This seems to me like a way of “completing” a set of functions.

Tagged under functional analysis since my motivation for asking this comes from Banach algebras of continuous functions on compact spaces.

Comment: If $X$ is compact with respect to this topology, then it's necessary and sufficient that $A$ separate points and be closed under addition, multiplication, scalar multiplication, complex conjugation, and limits with respect to the sup norm. This follows from Stone-Weierstrass, and it's not even necessary that the topology be initial.

Comment: ("Compact" should be "compact Hausdorff," whoops.)